# Received unregistered task using Celery with Django

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I have celery setup with a Django project and I can't seem to get my task to run properly.  I'm using Django 1.4.3, celery 3.0.1, django-celery 3.0.17 and Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 13.04.

I have verified my rabbitmq-server is running:

```
sudo service rabbitmq-server status
Status of node rabbit@fenster ...
[{pid,1667},
 {running_applications,[{rabbit,"RabbitMQ","3.0.2"},
                        {os_mon,"CPO  CXC 138 46","2.2.9"},
                        {mnesia,"MNESIA  CXC 138 12","4.7"},
                        {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","2.2.1"},
                        {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","1.18.1"},
                        {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","2.15.1"}]},
 {os,{unix,linux}},
 {erlang_version,"Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:30] [kernel-poll:true]\n"},
 {memory,[{total,28112760},
          {connection_procs,93432},
          {queue_procs,42680},
          {plugins,0},
          {other_proc,9331824},
          {mnesia,65288},
          {mgmt_db,0},
          {msg_index,86656},
          {other_ets,764048},
          {binary,1343288},
          {code,12372068},
          {atom,512601},
          {other_system,3500875}]},
 {vm_memory_high_watermark,0.4},
 {vm_memory_limit,6719406080},
 {disk_free_limit,1000000000},
 {disk_free,122925531136},
 {file_descriptors,[{total_limit,924},
                    {total_used,7},
                    {sockets_limit,829},
                    {sockets_used,3}]},
 {processes,[{limit,1048576},{used,151}]},
 {run_queue,0},
 {uptime,275789}]
...done.
```

I have my Django project setup in a virtualenv.  I have celery configured in the settings.py file as:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # django apps

    # our apps ...

    # third party modules ...
    'djcelery',
]

import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()

CELERY_IMPORTS = ('my.task')
```

The RabbitMQ broker is setup properly - we have other celery tasks running properly.

My task:

```
import celery

class MyClass(object):

    @celery.task()
    def my_task(self, new, old):
        # do stuff
        return

    def kick_off_tasks(self):
        # do stuff
        new = 'something'
        old = 'something else'
        self.my_task.apply_async(args(new, old), kwarg1='new', kwarg2='old)
        # do more stuff
```

When I run the view that calls `kick_off_tasks` I receive the following in the celeryd info log:

```
./manage.py celeryd --loglevel=info

[Tasks]
  . my.task
  . other.tasks
  . more.tasks
  . etc.etc.etc

[2013-08-23 14:18:40,772: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@fenster has started.
[2013-08-23 14:20:40,757: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'my.task'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you are using relative imports?
Please see http://bit.ly/gLye1c for more information.

The full contents of the message body was:
{'retries': 0, 'task': 'my.task', 'eta': None, 'args': ('something, 'something else'), 'expires': None, 'callbacks': None, 'errbacks': None, 'kwargs': {}, 'id': 'bf4d5ee7-9701-42b6-a887-c6b6470d9810', 'utc': True} (2297b)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ricomoss/.virtualenvs/proton/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 394, in on_task_received
    strategies[name](message, body, message.ack_log_error)
KeyError: 'my.task'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this working by refactoring so that the tasks were not class methods.  I placed them in our `tasks.py` file and everything works fine.  I haven't had time to research why this is the case, which I plan to do, but until then if anyone is having the same problem you'll have a quick fix available.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to make class methods function as tasks? I'm having a similar problem. Currently I'm using a `tasks.py` file to call the class methods when I want to run them in the background but I would much rather be able to call them directly.

Comment: @Matthew I've never been able to successfully task a class or class method.  I believe it has something to do with the way it's pickled, but I haven't ever taken the time to understand what the underlying problem is.